# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Tags: drivers, database, sql, mssql, odbc

I am not able to run `sqlcmd` command 

My OS (18.04) is

> $ uname -a Linux Linux 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23
>   18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
$ sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'password'
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Comment: You might find [this useful](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

we have same problem,

and i have fixed that,
just replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`

`sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U SA`